# What is the best way to create an authentic weatherboard wall?

Tags: building, design

I am working on a house where I want to create a weatherboard look for the outside walls.  I'm not certain the best way to go about this.

Currently I'm using the horizontal side of a 1x2 profile brick:

[image: 1x2 Profile brick]

Which gives the following appearance:

[image: Weatherboard wall]

I am wondering though if there are any better techniques to create the weatherboard look:

[image: A genuine weatherboard exterior]

It seems that the 1x2 profile brick has its ridges roughly twice as dense as a true weatherboard exterior.

One advantage of these profile bricks is that their reverse side gives the interior a VJ (tongue and groove) look, which is the interior look of the house that I am trying to model.

[image: VJ interior walls]

However, the lack of anything larger than 1x2 and the overly dense ridges means that I'm leaning towards looking for other options.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/matijagrguric/6050861052/in/album-72157627449889664/)?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use the relatively new [bricks with masonry profile](http://rebrickable.com/parts/98283):

[image: 98283]

If you aren't aware, the reverse side of these bricks includes the horizontal lines but leaves out the vertical ones. This allows you to create something like this:

[image: prototype]

This solutions provides the advantage of less dense horizontal lines, but being that this is a newer part, it also really limits your color selection.

Your pictures make it look like you are trying to build a white house, which is currently impossible using this part as it isn't available in white. The best that you could do is light gray, which is what I used in my example.

There is a [1x4 version](http://rebrickable.com/parts/15533) of this part that would make construction much easier and sturdier, but it's only available in medium dark flesh at the moment:

[image: 15533]

This construction also leaves you with a brick pattern on the inside of your wall. It doesn't sound like this is what you want. One solution would be to create a double wide wall, but that may not be feasible in your case.

Comment: This would be a good solution, except for the colours.  I am creating a white house.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of brick-intensive approaches to this.  Here's a few:

This flickr user (Andrew) has an example, but the "how to" image on the next slide is hard to figure out: https://www.flickr.com/photos/8215600@N03/5223554342/in/photostream/

This is one for a roof, but the same technique could be used for a wall: https://flic.kr/p/a3PcXk

Also, I suggest taking a look at the Lego Techniques Flickr group for different wall techniques: https://www.flickr.com/groups/788191@N24/

Comment: This definitely looks gorgeous, but will cramp the interior.  I really like this solution though.